# How do I enable the GRUB menu on a dual boot startup, without admin rights?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, linux-mint

I set the grub timer to 0 from Linux, to make it automatically go to the selected OS without displaying the menu, but it was accidentally set to Windows. I do not have admin privileges in Windows or the BIOS, I do have them in the now inaccessible Linux, though. How can I boot to Linux? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am locked out of everything right now. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your access to Windows or BIOS is not relevant to make changes to grub... Press and hold the shift key (sometimes specifically the right shift) during boot to see if you can get to the grub menu, otherwise in some cases a well timed ESC is required to access the grub menu. Once there you can boot Linux and make the necessary changes.